# How to reduce coupling when one class calls only one method on another class that has many methods?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, coupling

I have a class (let's call it `MyService`) that accepts two dependencies in it's constructor.  The first one is not all that relevant to the question.  The second one is `PaymentDetails`.  PaymentDetails lives for longer than the MyService, which is created by a factory to process this particular request.

In `MyService.process()`, it:

- does some stuff with the first dependency,
- constructs a `new TransactionDetails()` object and sets various things on it,
- calls `myPaymentDetails.setTransactionDetails( td );`
- returns something to say which page in the wizard follows next

`PaymentDetails` has by necessity many methods on it.  It is an Entity style object into which information is built up as the user steps through a series of about 5 pages.

What is bothering me is that as written my service class depends on the whole of `PaymentDetails` but only calls one single method.

This bothers me because:

- it will limit the ability to re-use the service class
- it is not possible to understand what the real dependencies are by reading the method signatures

My question is:

What is the best way to fix this so that my service class has minimal dependencies?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could create a simple interface:

```
public interface TransactionAcceptor {
    void setTransactionDetails(TransactionDetails td);
}
```

Have `PaymentDetails` declare that it implement the interface:

```
public class PaymentDetails implements TransactionAcceptor {
    ...
}
```

And of course it already implements the required method. Then `MyService` only needs to deal with the `TransactionAcceptor` interface and not be coupled with `PaymentDetails`.

Answer (score 4):

Add an `interface Transactionable` or something and let PaymentDetails implement it.
In MyService deal with 'Transactionables' only.